# Set audio unit device in AudioKit 5 (macOS)

Tags: macos, audiokit

Previous version of AudioKit had `AKMicrophone.setDevice(_:)`, but since `AKMicrophone` was removed in v5, what is the correct way to get input from a device other than the default (on macOS)?

Here's what I've tried so far (map is called with a valid device ID, of that I'm sure):

```swift
func map(in: AudioDeviceID) {
  let engine = AudioEngine()

  let inUnit = engine.avEngine.inputNode.audioUnit!
  setDevice(for: inUnit, to: `in`)

  engine.output = engine.input
  try! engine.start()
}

private func setDevice(for unit: AudioUnit, to id: AudioDeviceID) {
  var deviceId = id;
  let err = AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &deviceId, UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size))
  if (err != noErr) {
    print(err)
    assert(false)
  }
}
```

But when it calls `engine.start()` it crashes with:

```
2021-02-12 01:02:27.304545-0600 Roundabout[24616:587679] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:88    required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1408:Initialize: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(outputHWFormat))]
```

Removing the `setDevice` call works, but then it's just passing the default microphone through, which is not what I want.